# Как получить первые слова в предложении после запятой на php?

Tags: php

Исходный текст: **Раз два, три четыре пять, два восемь, один**

Нужно получить: **Раз, три, два, один**

Подскажите пожалуйста готовое решение.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = '';
$string = 'Раз два, три четыре пять, два восемь, один';
$strings = explode(',', $string);

foreach($strings as $key => $string) {
    $words = explode(' ',trim($string));
    $word = $words[0];
    $result .= $word;
    if ($key + 1 < count($strings)) {
        $result .= ', ';
    }
}
```

В `$result` будет `Раз, три, два, один`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'Раз два, три четыре пять, два восемь, один';

echo implode(', ', array_map(fn ($word) => strtok($word, ' '), explode(', ', $string)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я просто привык решать такие проблемы регулярками, но...

```
$string = 'Раз два, три четыре пять, два восемь, один';

if (preg_match_all('~(,|^)\\s*(?<word>\\w+)~u', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches['word']);
}
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
   [0]=>
   string(6) "Раз"
   [1]=>
   string(6) "три"
   [2]=>
   string(6) "два"
   [3]=>
   string(8) "один"
 }
```

Поковырять и потыкать регулярку с подробным разбором:
https://regex101.com/r/dbfgOr/1